# Simulate Keyboard Strokes C++ On Mac

Tags: c++, macos, keyboard-events, intel-edison

I am working with the Intel Edison board and mainly trying to program in C++ to simulate keyboard strokes on a computer. Mainly programming it on my Macbook Pro.

Most solutions online either use different language, or uses some Visual studio solution. Examples: Keyboard.press('A'); would be like someone pressed A.

I just wanted some pointers in the right direction, so that I can learn how to do this, or if you could share code that would be excellent.

Comment: So is this about the Edison or OS X?

Comment: This is about creating a program on the Edison to simulate keyboard events